# How to navigate to next fragment after popbackstack

Tags: android, fragment

I have n number of fragments ( which contain dynamic views ). Lets say Fragment A->B->C. Now when i press back (using popbackstack), its A->B. Now when click next to go to Fragment C, i'm getting a null pointer exception on "getFragmentManager". How to achieve this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        RequirementFragment.reqIndex = RequirementFragment.reqIndex -1;
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

There is a next button in the app, which takes to the next fragment. Below code is the next button onclick funtion.

```
private void goToNextQuestion() {

        Activity parentActivity = getActivity();
        FragmentManager fm = parentActivity.getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        RequirementFragment nextQuestion = new RequirementFragment();
        nextQuestion.setArguments(getFragmentAttribs(reqIndex + 1));

        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
        ft.replace(R.id.s6_lin_layout_question_wrapper, nextQuestion);
        ft.addToBackStack(String.valueOf(reqIndex));
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.app.Activity.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at mobileapp.fragments.RequirementFragment.getTextBoxSubmission(RequirementFragment.java:605)
            at mobileapp.fragments.RequirementFragment.saveRequirementSubmission(RequirementFragment.java:774)
            at mobileapp.fragments.RequirementFragment.goToNextQuestion(RequirementFragment.java:836)
            at com.localoye.mobileapp.fragments.RequirementFragment.access$100(RequirementFragment.java:73)
            at com.localoye.mobileapp.fragments.RequirementFragment$2.onClick(RequirementFragment.java:149)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Can you please post the output from Logcat?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. popBackStack() removes the instance of the current fragment, so when you again call the fragment which is popped already using (callfragmentbytag), it will return null. So the only possible way is to "add/hide" fragments in such scenario and not to use "replace".

Override backbutton press to take back to previous fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment, String classTag ) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(classTag) != null) {
            LogUtility.printInfoMessage(CLASSTAG+":loadFragment -- fragment already loaded "+classTag);
            return;
        }

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.summaryFragmentContainer, fragment, classTag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```